# Customizing WooCommerce e-mail templates

Tags: templates, woocommerce, html-email

I have used WooCommerce before, but have never done much customization to it until recently.

I customized the e-mail templates to show the payment information, like transaction number, etc.

This works fine except for one thing.

Right now if a person pays with PayPal the process goes like this:

– order is placed, and is pending payment
– user goes to paypal and makes a payment
– PayPal IPN message is received, order is updated to "processing"
– email is sent to user

However this e-mail does not have the payment info in it. The variables are empty. If I re-send the same e-mail manually it works as expected. other automated e-mails that go out during the order process work fine, it's just that initial e-mail that's missing the information.

What I don’t get is why it's missing the first time, when the PayPal IPN is received, and the transaction info with it, before the e-mail is even sent.

Since the IPN is received before the e-mail is sent why is that info not in the e-mail? If I go to the order and re-send the “processing” e-mail it has the info that we want it to show.

Or maybe even a way to have PayPal orders automatically put "on hold" would work, then when I manually change the order status the e-mail would be sent with the correct information.

Comment: A plugin like that won't work for this problem. The emails work fine if I manually send them. The issue I'm trying to solve relates to how the e-mail behaves when a PayPal IPN message is received. That cannot be tested with a general e-mail testing plugin.

Comment: This plugin is just for testing some outputs… It doesn't solve anything, I know… But it can help when testing code related to WooCommerce email notifications. I have very well understood your issue, thanks. Your question is poor regarding the code that you are using. Re-sending manually the 'processing' email notification has nothing to do with the 'new order' notification that is sent automatically for all kind (statuses) of new orders…